# *For* instead of *of* and *prices*

Tags: word-choice

Can I use *for* instead of *of* and *prices* instead of *price* in my sentence?

"I was surprised by the price(s) for/of vegetables and fruit."

Comment: _For_  is not idiomatic in this context. "The greengrocer charges high prices for his vegetables", but "the price of vegetables". No logical explanation that I know of, it's just 'the way we say it'.

Comment: And it should be "price" not "prices", or is "prices" also correct?

Comment: "The price of XXX" is a set phrase, even when a range of similar commodities is being referred to.